# Retain rotate, zoom and pan in Plot3D generated inside a Palette

Tags: graphics3d, packages, version-12

Consider the following `.wl` package:

```
BeginPackage["ColorsIn3DPlot`"];


Begin["MyPrivate`"]


CreatePalette[Manipulate[
  Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, ColorFunction -> color,
   ImageSize -> {480, 480}],
  {color, {"Rainbow", "NeonColors", "BlueGreenYellow"}}],
 WindowFloating -> True,
 WindowSize -> All,
 WindowTitle -> "Nice Plot",
 Saveable -> False];


End[];


EndPackage[];
```

Clicking on `► Run All Code` at the top right corner of the so-called "Package Helper" indeed outputs a palette with the 3D graphics, but no interactivity is enabled.

Can anyone point out the reason to why it is so?

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: Version 12.0 on windowd 10.

Comment: Just tried it once again on Mac OS X, running version 12.2, and still, no 3d interactivity is there.

Comment: What seems to help is adding the option ``StyleDefinitions -> ""`` to ``CreatePalette``, therefore a problem lies in the defaulty ``Palette.nb`` style. However, this makes the palette window include the top Wolfram Mathematica bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `WindowClickSelect -> True` to `CreatePalette`.

```
CreatePalette[
  Manipulate[
   Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, ColorFunction -> color, 
    ImageSize -> {480, 480}], {color, {"Rainbow", "NeonColors", 
     "BlueGreenYellow"}}], WindowFloating -> True, WindowSize -> All, 
  WindowTitle -> "Nice Plot", WindowClickSelect -> True, 
  Saveable -> False];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! So it is not related in any way to the package file. I should change the question title then.